# System not mounting encrypted device on boot, can manually use BusyBox

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, luks

With a recent update I was forced to use boot-repair to fix my boot sector.

Previously, when booting to Ubuntu I'd get a prompt for password at boot to decrypt my root partition. Now I get thrown to BusyBox with an unmounted root. On BusyBox I can manually mount the root  by issuing: `cryptsetup open /dev/sda3 crypt` and then `mount /dev/vgkubuntu /`. Exiting BusyBox after that seems to work and resume the regular boot.

How can I boot and mount root without having to do that manually from BusyBox every time?

Grub setting:

```
load_video
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt2'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa
fi
linux   /vmlinuz-5.11.0-16-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
initrd  /initrd.img-5.11.0-16-generic
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like reinstalling the kernel image did it.